# what does ( if [ -z "$1" ] ) condition means in bash programming

Tags: bash, macos

i have a script as below :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Missing output folder name"
        exit 1
fi

split -l 10000 --additional-suffix=.ordtmp orders.txt orders

for f in `ls *.ordtmp`; do
        if [ "$2" == "local" ]; then
                mv $f $1
        else
                hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal $f $1
                rm -f $f
        fi
        sleep 3
done
```

When I try to run it, i get the error as :

```
(base) 01HW993798:ch06 tcssig$ ./splitAndSend.sh
Missing output folder name
```

Is the file expecting an output folder to be mentioned at he runtime ?

Comment: The loop has numerous problems; run your code through https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$1` means an input argument and `-z` means non-defined or empty

You’re testing whether an input argument to the script was defined when running the script